# Table Merge based on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have these 2 tables with the same column names and schema, and I would like to join them while having all the rows from Table_1 and only new rows from Table_2.

Table_1

```
child_id    parent_id
11               1
12               1
13               1
14               2
15               2
```

Table_2

```
child_id    parent_id
9                 9
10               10   
11               11
12               12
13               13
14               14
15               15
16               16
```

the final output that I would like to achieve is:

```
child_id    parent_id
9                 9
10               10   
11               1
12               1
13               1
14               2
15               2
16               16
```

PS: I'm working on AWS Athena

I tried the anti-join

```
SELECT child_id, parent_id
FROM table_1
UNION (
SELECT child_id, parent_id
FROM table_2
WHERE child_id not in table_1
)
```

but Athena says : Multiple columns returned by subquery are not yet supported

Comment: I think if you remove the `(` and `)` which are not necessary, it will stop looking like a subquery, because a UNION is not a sub query

Answer (score 0):

Try using `select` subquery for `not in` condition:

```sql
SELECT child_id, parent_id
FROM table_1
UNION
(SELECT child_id, parent_id
 FROM table_2
 WHERE child_id not in
       (SELECT child_id FROM table_1))
```